# How to create a json file with ndjson schema?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ndjson

How do I create an ndjson file in Visual Studio using the correct schema.
At the moment I am getting the following error because my json is not being recognised. I know it is correct because I'm able to issue a Web request via Fiddler with it.

[image]

Comment: Are you saving this as a .json or .ndjson file? Looks like VS thinks it's a JSON file.

Comment: @Relequestual saving as a .json. I didn't realise there was such thing as a .ndjson file, should I save as this instead? I suppose I cant use JSON Path to manipulate it either?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. I just did a google and found a plugin which expects .ndjson extension to recognise NDJSON files: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=buster.ndjson-colorizer

Comment: Have you read the spec for NDJSON? Your file is not a valid NDJSON file. It cannot have newlines except to separate JSON elements. The real problem is still that you need the extension to have it recognize the new filetype.

Comment: @RedX Thanks for the info however the JSON schema formatted it for me, I didn't insert the newlines myself :)

Comment: I saved it as a .ndjson already - thanks.